# Uncaught ReferenceError: WebKitPoint is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, extjs, sencha-touch

I use Sencha Touch 1.1.1

Yesterday when Google Chrome was updated to 39 it has started to give this error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: WebKitPoint is not defined
```

Because they have removed WebKitPoint. Sencha Touch has a code with WebKitPoint, located here http://cdn.sencha.io/touch/sencha-touch-1.1.1/sencha-touch.js at line 6. Yeah.

```
getXY: function() {
    var a = window.webkitConvertPointFromNodeToPage(this.dom, new WebKitPoint(0, 0));
    return [a.x, a.y]
}
```

I think WebKitPoint is some kind of function object {x:0, y:0} but I was unable to make/create what the JavaScript code wants; I wrote this `WebKitPoint = {x:0, y:0}` but it gives error again, this time says that it is not a function.

Also I have found this: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/pIbpN_8Lqpg

tl;dr
Google Chrome 39 no longer supports WebKitPoin. How can I emulate or replace it?

Comment: Sorry I broke your stuff, I hope the getBoundingClientRect() fix works out.

Comment: @foolip, np, Ahmad has pointed a workaround. We should have moved to Sencha Touch 2, version 1 is not supported anymore.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try replacing

```
var point = window.webkitConvertPointFromNodeToPage(this.dom, new WebKitPoint(0, 0));
return [point.x, point.y]
```

with

```
var rect = this.dom.getBoundingClientRect();
return [rect.left, rect.top];
```

Source: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=434976#c10

Code Credits: Philip Jägenstedt

Comment: As I mentioned in the Chromium bug, there is one caveat. If you're using CSS transforms to rotate elements, getBoundingClientRect() is not equivalent, as it will instead return the top-left coordinate of the bounding box of the rotated box.

Answer (score 3):

Following on Ahmad's excellent answer, you could also just override everything at the beginning of your script (before sencha-touch.js is loaded):

```
WebKitPoint = function(x,y) { };
window.webkitConvertPointFromNodeToPage = function(dom, unusedWebKitPoint) {
    var rect = dom.getBoundingClientRect();
    return [rect.left, rect.top];
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Dave, this is great. But I became a scrolling problem in my views. I think you have to return an associative array:

```js
WebKitPoint = function(x,y) { };
window.webkitConvertPointFromNodeToPage = function(dom, unusedWebKitPoint) {
    var rect = dom.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      'x': rect.left,
      'y': rect.top
    }
};
```